# Understanding the meaning of amplitude in FFT

Tags: fourier-transform

I am recording data with a magnetometer of the background magnetic field in a building. I have applied the FFT algorithm to the data in order to look for the frequencies that appear in it. I would like to use this in order to identify (or at least make an educated guess) of the sources of the disturbances that I observe.

My question is: What is the meaning that I can attribute to the amplitude that I obtain from the FFT algorithm? Is there some unit that can be ascribed to it?

Looking at the formula for the continuous fourier transform (which I took from Wolfram Mathworld) :
\begin{align}
f(\nu)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi i \nu t} \mathrm{d}t
\end{align} 
I do not really know how to accomodate the dimension of Tesla in there.

Thank you

Comment: what are the units of your input data?

Comment: The unit of the data is nanoTesla

Comment: The **t** here refers to time? So you've measured time variation of the magnitude of the local magnetic field at a particular position coordinate?

Comment: @Fat32 That is indeed what I have measured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The continuous-time Fourier transform of a function $f(t)$ is in essence an integration of $f(t)$ multiplied with a complex exponential kernel:
$$ F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt \tag{1}$$

Since the exponential function is unitless, the unit of the Fourier integral will be the multiplication of the units of the function $f(t)$ and the differential $dt$.

Assuming that the function $f(t)$ had a unit of *micro Tesla*, and its argument $t$ is time (in seconds), then the unit of $dt$ will be *seconds*. As a consequence, the unit of the Fourier transform, $F(\omega)$, will be  **micro Tesla  second**  $$\mu T \cdot s \tag{2}$$

However, what you actually compute is the discrete-time Fourier transform, $F(e^{j\omega})$, of the samples $f[n]= f(nT_s)$ of the function $f(t)$, via the summation: $$F(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f[n] e^{-j\omega n} \tag{3}$$ where $T_s$ is the sampling period in seconds.

Furthermore, instead of the continuous-argument function $F(e^{j\omega})$, you will compute its samples $F[k]$

$$ F[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N} n k} \tag{4}$$

through a DFT (discrete Fourier transform) of the samples $f[n]$ of length $N$, possibly implemented with an FFT algorithm.

The unit of the samples $f[n]$ is the same as the unit of $f(t)$, making the unit of $F(e^{j\omega})$  and $F[k]$ as *micro Tesla*. Therefore the unit of the FFT samples $F[k]$ of $F(e^{j\omega})$ will be **micro Tesla**.

Note that there is an (implicit) amplitude [scaling](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41835/signal-amplitude-to-fft-amplitude/41849#41849) by $1/T_s$ in the computed DFT samples $F[k]$, and when you want to display the continuous-time Fourier transform $F(\omega)$ from the samples $F[k]$, you multiply them with $T_s$, which corrects not only the amplitude scaling, but also the unit of it, by making it **micro Tesla second** as in (2).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a detailed answer.