# Plot the spectrum and n-point DFT

Tags: frequency-spectrum, sampling, dft

$x_a(t) = \cos(2\pi f_a t)$ was sampled with sampling period $T_s$. Plot the { spectrum | $N$-point DFT } of $x[n]$ ($f_a$, $T_s$ or $f_s$ given, $N$ given - whole number of periods or not).

Anyone can help?

Comment: Hi! plot with Matlab / Octave ?

Comment: @Fat32 It's enough to plot it just on a piece of paper.

Comment: ok. So where is the difficult part ?

Comment: @Fat32 I don't know how to even start or how it should look like.

Comment: can you plot the spectrum of $x[n] = \delta[n]$ ?

Comment: @Fat32 not really

Comment: why not ? if so why do you want to plot the spectrum of $x[n] = \cos(w_0 n)$ then ? Are you a student ?

Comment: @Fat32 Yeah, I am student and all I need is passing a lab entrance test. ;)

Comment: ok ;-) the lab is tomorrow at least I believe ? you have plenty of time to learn the spectrum of $x[n]= \delta[n]$ ? I will prepare an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Your signal $x(t) = \cos(2 \pi f_a t)$ is an ideally defined infinite length signal, and the process of representing its DFT spectrum can be accomodated by the following **windowing** argument:

Let $x_d[n]=x(nT)=\cos(2 \pi f_a T_s n)$ be an ideally defined infinite length discrete-time sequence resulting of sampling ideally defined infinitely long continuous-time signal $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_a t)$. And let a practically defined finite length truncated verison of $x_d[n]$ be

$$x[n] = x_d[n] w[n] $$

where $w[n]$ is a rectangular window of length $N$ samples and is used to truncate $x_d[n]$ according to:

$$ w[n] = \begin{cases} 1 &, 0 \leq n \leq N-1 \\ 0 &, \text{ otherwise } \\ \end{cases} $$

At this very point one can simply write down the $N$-point DFT sum equation as

$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{ -j\frac{2\pi}{N} k n } = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos(2\pi f_a T_s n) e^{ -j \frac{2\pi}{N} k n } $$ and with the help of Euler identity for the cosine you get :

$$ 
\begin{align}
X[k] &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} 0.5 \left( e^{j \frac{2\pi f_a} {F_s}n} +e^{-j \frac{2\pi f_a} {F_s}n} \right)   e^{ -j\frac{2\pi}{N} k n } \\
&  = 0.5 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j \frac{2\pi f_a} {F_s}n}  e^{ -j\frac{2\pi}{N} k n } + 0.5 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-j \frac{2\pi f_a} {F_s}n}  e^{ -j\frac{2\pi}{N} k n }\\
&= 0.5 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j 2\pi ( \frac{f_a}{F_s}- \frac{k}{N}) n} + 0.5 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-j 2\pi ( \frac{f_a}{F_s}+ \frac{k}{N}) n}\\
\end{align}$$

Now those exponential sums can be cast into a geometric sum formula and yield the following:

$$ \boxed{  X[k] =  0.5  \frac{ 1 - e^{j 2\pi ( \frac{f_a}{F_s}- \frac{k}{N}) N}}{1 - e^{j 2\pi ( \frac{f_a}{F_s}- \frac{k}{N}) } } + 0.5 \frac{ 1 - e^{-j 2\pi ( \frac{f_a}{F_s}+ \frac{k}{N}) N}} {1 - e^{-j 2\pi ( \frac{f_a}{F_s}+ \frac{k}{N}) } }  ~~~, k = 0,1,2,...,N-1 }$$

Now depending on the relation between $f_a$, $F_s$ and $N$, you will typically have two distinct looking kind of spectrums.

First case assumes that the factor $ (\frac{f_a}{F_s} - \frac{k}{N})N = \frac{f_a N}{F_s} - k $  is an **integer**; equivalently $\frac{f_a N }{F_s}$ is an integer. When this is the case The spectrum will be full of zeros for all $k$ except at two points where $ k = \pm \frac{ f_s N }{ F_s} $. And at those points the magnitude will be $X[k] = N/2$.

For all other cases for which the ratio $\frac{f_a N}{F_s}$ is not an integer, then you will have a **sinc** type DFT spectrum and which is more typically observed in general. You should evaluate that for each $k$. Indees it's the DFT of a rectangular window (all ones), shifted to cosine frequency locations and sampled at those $k$ index frequencies.

A simple matlab /octave program confirms the results:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

fa = 2300;
Fs = 8000;
N = 81;

Ts = 1/Fs;
n = 0:N-1;

x = cos(2*pi*fa*n*Ts);      % Get truncated discrete-time sequence x[n].

X = fft(x,N);               % Get N-point DFT of x[n] via FFT function.

% Check our hand derivation:
k = 0:N-1 ;
Xk = 0.5* (  ( 1 - exp(-j*2*pi*( fa/Fs - k/N )*N))./(1 - exp(-j*2*pi*( fa/Fs - k/N ))))...
    + 0.5* (  ( 1 - exp(j*2*pi*( fa/Fs + k/N )*N))./(1 - exp(j*2*pi*( fa/Fs + k/N )))) ;

Xk(isnan(Xk)) = N/2;        % recover divide-by-zero when fa*N/Fs is an integer.

figure,stem(k,abs(X),'g')
hold on
stem(k,abs(Xk),'r+')
title([num2str(N),'-point DFT magnitude, |X[k]|, when the ratio (f_a N/F_s) is NOT an Integer']);
legend('via FFT','','by Hand');
```

with the following plots for $N=80$ and $N=81$ :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out my blog article at https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php for how to greatly simplify your "by hand" formula.  The result is equation (25).  I have not seen this simplification anywhere else.  The greatest advantage of the simplified formula is that it can be inverted.  That is, the exact frequency of a single pure real tone in a DFT can be found from three bin values.  I have been told repeatedly that an exact frequency formula is not possible, yet the first one I found is in my next article.  Subsequent articles have other exact frequency formulas.

Comment: @CedronDawg the *three bin exact frequency* computaion of a pure tone from its noise free DFT is also very nice example. Well appreciated your effort. Eventhough I already have it in my Matlab code base. You know that it requires very high SNR to be applied. And only single tone or you should modify the formula a bit ;-)...

Comment: I've added an answer to this post to show you what I mean by it being simplified.  I am very interested in your claim that you have my formula in your MATLAB toolbox.  Can you provide an online link to some documentation?  The formula is actually quite robust in the presence of noise.  Check out the reference to an independent evaluation made by Julien Arzi in the "Afterword".  Jacobsen's Estimator is an approximation of my formula and has similar robustness.  I have an even more robust formula in the pipeline.

Comment: @CedronDawg Nooo I'm sorry, I didn't mean I had *your formula* in one of my matlab toolboxes, I wanted to say I have already coded a *three DFT point exact sine frequency computation* program by myself into my own codebase m-file (not in a toolbox) :-). Now reading your comment on "robust to noise" so probably they are not the same. I should read your formula better then... Becuse my simple derivation assumes that all DFT value are belonging to the pure sine **signal** , if there is noise, then DFT values will change hence the frequency estimation. How robust is your algorithm? SNR ?

Comment: The comparison paper can be found in the first link under the "Resources:" header in the gray box on the upper right on this page:  http://www.tsdconseil.fr/log/scriptscilab/festim/index-en.html.  You will see that mine was best in both low and high noise tests, especially the low noise cases.  He provides a test case framework in SCILAB so you should be able to test yours in comparison.

Comment: I have derived several formulas since, including a two bin version at https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1095.php.  The two bin formula is more robust in peaks between two bins than the three bin version.  I thought I had found the most robust three bin formula in https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1108.php, but the one I have in the pipe line is about half as sensitive to noise.  My email address can be found in my profile, I would appreciate it if you could send me a copy of your formula so I can give it a look.

Comment: Hi @CedronDawg.  This [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41835/signal-amplitude-to-fft-amplitude/41849#41849) of mine already includes a computation (approximate) of single sine amplitude from a single point on DFT. It's actually trivial. Some one downvoted it for no reasons? May be you can find it interesing. In the mean time I'm looking for the code where I have implemented the three point (or two) code. Note however that I dont think it qualifies as an **algorithm** but just a few lines of equations.

Comment: while writing the comment I noticed that it's computing the **amplitude** and not the frequency. But I remember it as a fequency estimation, dont know why. Either remember it wrong or I cannot find the code yet. But I do really remember writing the matlab lines. So let me check my code base for that...

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I noticed that and that is still an approximation.  You can find an exact (and robust) solution at https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/787.php.  You can also find the list of my blog articles by clicking on the red "Cedron Dawg" author tag.  The distinction between approximation and exact is important.  I have found most "experts" won't look over my work after I claim exactness believing erroneously that it is impossible.  Not only is it possible, but I have done it many different ways.  This is why I finally decided to put it out there for everyone to see in my articles.

Comment: @CedronDawg Yes that's very interesting... When I looked at your page at dsprelated, having seen the *3 point exact frequency estimation algorithm* (only looking at its name) I said "oh yes I've already coded this" :-) And I really "remember" the feeling of having done that. But now neither the code nor the algorithm is available :-) ? Probably kind of an illusion happened to me while visiting the page... I will pay more attention to your algorithm, now.

Comment: @CedronDawg Hi! Now I've read your article 1095. That's very great! The use of linear algebra within the help of simplified DFT formula and some vector operations yield an otherwise hardly analytic problem into a neat algebraically solvable form. Requires great deal of imagination. Btw, today I've also derived a numerically exact  frequency computation of a single exponential tone. But double exponents make it complicated. Noise performance is down to 4 decimal places at 40 dB SNR. I mean my solution is just at the level of a homework project assignment, do not expect something great :-)

Comment: I truly appreciate your words.  Believe it or not, this is the first feedback that I have gotten that indicates that somebody understands what I did.  You can compare your complex tone exact frequency formula to my two bin (1039) and three bin (1043) versions.  Bringing the subject back to the topic of this post, you can find an alternative form of the simplified bin value equation in https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1120.php.  In equation (18) you will find the Dirichlet kernel, aka the aliased sinc function.  The sinc function pertains to pure complex tones in the continuous case.

Comment: @CedronDawg Really? Quite surprising because it's very clearly described there. I have already coded it and now it works great, exactly ! Congradulations. I also used noise and got about 4 digit correctness at 40 dB (similar to my simple Numerical solution of a single c.exp from a single DFT bin. However compared to a numerical method, this algorithm stands at a completely different category. Btw. I believe it's possible improve the noisy estimation accuracy by evaluating the equation at more points and getting an overdetermined system of equations and a LSE solution? Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but it is still an open question.  Right now it stands at "it depends".  Additional bins bring in more signal information and reduces the average variance, but it does so with increasingly poor SNRs.  The vector based formulas are readily extensible so I would be obliged if you tested your hypothesis yourself without being prejudiced with my results.  I also hope you take the time to review all the other formulas I have derived.  As far as I know, they are all novel.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the signal defined as a discrete sequence provided in Fat32's answer.

$$ x[n] = \cos( 2\pi \cdot f_a \cdot T_s n ) $$

With a simple variable substitution, this definition can be greatly simplified.

$$ \alpha = 2\pi \cdot f_a \cdot T_s $$

Here are the the units for the values in the equation:

$$ \frac{radians}{sample} = \frac{radians}{cycle} \cdot \frac{cycle}{second} \cdot \frac{seconds}{sample} $$

I find knowing the units tends to make equations a lot more understandable.  The signal now looks like this:

$$ x[n] = \cos( \alpha n ) $$

Note that the units in the argument are really simple.

$$ \frac{radians}{sample} \cdot samples = radians $$

Next, let's precalculate two real values:

$$ U = x[N] - x[0] $$
$$ V = x[N-1] - x[-1] $$

When there are a whole number of cycles within the sample frame, both these values will be zero.

Lastly, define the relative location of each bin around the complex unit circle:

$$ \beta_k = k \cdot \frac{ 2\pi }{ N } $$

Fat32's "by hand" equation is now equivalent to this:

$$  X[k] =  0.5 \left[  \frac{ Ue^{ i\beta_k }  - V }{ cos( \alpha ) - cos( \beta_k )}  \right], ~~~ k = 0,1,2,...,N-1 $$

As you can plainly see, not only does this form require significantly fewer calculations to evaluate, but it also comprehensible qualitatively.  The only complex valued term is in the exponent in the numerator.

The derivation can be found in my blog article [DFT Bin Value Formulas for Pure Real Tones](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php).  In the article a variable for the amplitude of the signal and a phase value is also included.  I also use a $1/N$ normalized DFT.  I highly recommend you read the "Qualitative Analysis" section to see how the equation explains the well known behavior of a single pure tone in a DFT.

In the whole cycle case, the equation becomes $0/0$ at bins $k_f$ and $(N-k_f)$, where $k_f$ is the bin corresponding to the cycles per frame of the signal.  Fat32's answer and my blog article explain how to deal with it.

I can pretty much guarantee that your professor has never seen this equation before.